# Eguchi-Hanson Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

It is my understanding that when one talks about the manifold given by the total space of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$, the metric usually put on this is the Eguchi-Hanson metric. I'd like to learn more about this metric, especially as it pertains to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$. Can anyone recommend a reference for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I myself benefit a lot from reading the preprint "Gluing Eguchi-Hanson metrics and a question of Page" of Brendle-Kapouleas, which is available here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0056

In particular, there are some calculations in section 2 of the preprint which contain some basic properties of the Eguchi-Hanson metric.